# How to use the definite article "the" when listing a number of things

Tags: definite-articles

One of the most difficult things for non native speakers are the definite / indefinite articles. I have doubts how to use the definite article when listing few things. The particular sentence is:

> In particular, I investigated the temperature of black holes and
>   thermal emission, gravitational lensing, gravitational red-shift and
>   gravitational waves.

The first occurrence of the definite article seems intuitively correct
to me i.e. `I investigated the temperature`, but shouldn't I use the
definite article with the other nouns from the listing?

> In particular, I investigated the temperature of black holes and
>   thermal emission, the gravitational lensing, the gravitational red-shift and the gravitational waves.

The latter case seems to be wrong, but since I would like to include it in my motivation letter, I would like to have a second opinion. For instance, if I had something like `the gravitational lensing from black holes`, the definite article would be fine.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I consider both to be correct - it's just what sounds best to you.

Comment: I am leaning towards the first one.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the first version. I hope that this will make my job application more attractive.